# Why is this the EBP register value?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, paging, osdev

I'm currently developing Operating System.

In the process of Paging, I'm creating a page fault handler.

```
write_cr0 : 
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, dword[ebp+8]
mov cr0, eax
pop ebp
retn
```

In the page fault handler, set the PG bit in the cr0 register to use the write_cr0 function above to turn paging off or on.

It is executed without error in process # 0 (idle process).
But,
If a shell process creates a new process and a page fault occurs,
The value of the EBP register pushed onto the stack is strange when popped.(0xffffffff)

I really do not know why. Tell me the solution, please.

Comment: Curious why you'd have to turn paging on and off inside the page fault handler? That could cause some serious problems.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think the value 0xffffffff is incorrect?

Comment: Are you able to show us your page fault handler code?

Comment: When push it, it is put in 0xc ...., but when pop it, it pops as 0xffffffff.

Comment: If you're turning off paging, perhaps the linear and physical addresses of esp don't match.

Answer (score 0):

The value of ebp that is pushed is the value in the caller. If the caller is the page fault handler and it hasn't used ebp for anything, then it still has the value it had before the page fault occurred.